# Simple rails :has_many 'none' query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do the following:

I've got a relation:

```
User :has_many TeamMemberships
```

I found what to find all the users that have no team_memberships.

I've got the following:

```
User.all.each do |u|
  if u.team_memberships.nil?
    puts u.id
  end
end
```

But it doesn't seem to be working; am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are no associated objects, it will return an empty array, not nil.  Try `.blank?` instead.

BTW, shouldn't it be

```
has_many :team_memberships
```

?

Btw2, here's a nicer way to get all the users who have no team_memberships:

```
users = User.find(:all, :include => [:team_memberships], :conditions => ["team_memberships.id is null"])
```

Comment: It is so Rails 2. Now this query won't work. It should be: `User.include(:team_memberships).where('team_memberships.id IS NULL')`.

Comment: ah yes, it is a bit old-school, you're right.  I didn't realise it wouldn't work in new rails, i assumed you could use either syntax.  thanks.